# Auto synronization between a sharepoint list and excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I have an excel document with pivots graphs and tables in reports library. I wanted to that the excel document should automatically get the data from the list via a data connection. Is there a way to do this without doing an export to excel in the list actions? If I can get the data to pull into excel automatically, then I don't have to though and create the graphs all the time.

So bottom line, I have an excel file that I need to map the fields in to the
fields in a sharepoint list in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Excel Services](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/11/03/excel-services-2010-overview.aspx) or something like or through other add-ins like [this one](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=8d9e2a99-f288-47c2-916b-2f32864f7b82&ID=589&Web=5e4647a0-e7d0-4626-b71c-b1ff06402465)